# Write a function that returns the average of a list of numbers

Tags: python, function

I am trying to write a function that reads a txt document containing names with  corresponding scores(floats), eg. `Li Ning, 9.8 9.7 9.6 9.3 9.4 9.8`. Each name (competitors) and corresponding numbers are on a newline in the doc. 
Function should return the highest average score, and the corresponding name. Average scores are to be calculated. The average score of a contestant is computed after discarding the best and worst scores.

```
def getWinner(filename):
    results = open(filename)
    results.readlines()
    winner = ''
    max_score = 0
        for line in results:
            tokens = line.split(',')    # split line using ',' separator   
            name = tokens[0]                 # get the name
            scores = sorted(map(float, tokens[1].split()))

            ave = [sum(scores[i])for i in range(1, len(scores)-1)]/(len(scores)-2)
            if ave > max_score:
                   winner = name           
                   max_score = ave        

return "%s [%d]" % (winner, max_score)
```

The error I am receiving is `Cannot iterate float` I am assuming this is contained in my calculation of average. Why is this?

Thanks for all the useful input! My updated code:

```
def getWinner(filename): 
    results = open(filename).readlines()        
    winner = ''   
    max_score =0 


    for line in results:
        tokens = line.split(',')    
        name =  tokens[0]                
        scores = map(float, tokens[1].split()) 
        ave = sum(scores[1:-1])/(len(scores) - 2)                    
        if ave > max_score:
           winner = name             
           max_score = ave         

    return "%s [%.1f]" % (winner, max_score)
```

The site in which i am learning python through (Pyschools) will return the correct result, but states 'Private test Failed'. Can anyone see any outstanding errors?
Thanks Again

Comment: Show us the whole, exact error message, traceback and all.

Comment: probably error at this line `results.readlines()`. You need to assign to smth and iterate over it.

Comment: @Lafexlos: While that line makes no sense and should be removed, it happens to not be the source of the problem. `for line in results` works just fine without `readlines`.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah. that's another thing also. just woke up. sorry about that.

Comment: You say "integers" but your example has decimals.

Comment: Side note: your `ave` and `max_score` are floats--are you sure you want to return `max_score` as `[%d]` (integer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is in the average computation. You're doing:

```
ave = [sum(scores[i])for i in range(1, len(scores)-1)]/(len(scores)-2)
```

The bracket notation is used in list comprehension. `result = [ f(x) for x in iterable ]` is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for x in iterable:
    result.append(f(x))
```

So in your case, your code translates to:

```
ave = []
for x in range(1, len(scores) - 1):
    ave.append(sum(scores[x]))
```

So not quite what you're looking for. Also, calling the `sum` function on a single number will fail, since `sum` expects an iterable to work. And then, afterwards, you're dividing the list by an integer, and python should (also) fail at this point.

So I suggest the following average computation method:

```
ave = sum(scores[1:-1])/(len(scores) - 2)
```

Comment: `sum(scores[x])` isn't equivalent to `scores[x]`. This is the proximate cause of the error; `sum` finds that it can't iterate over `scores[i]` and throws an error. `sum` needs an iterable to work with. The rest of the answer is good.

Comment: That's right. Didn't chek that, I assumed that the sum of a single number falled back to this number itself. I'll edit my answer accordingly